# ngModel - How to deal with its different behavior in different browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to deal with different behavior of `ngModel` in different browsers.

My directive wraps jqueryUI autocomplete and on its `select` event it calls `ngModel.$setViewValue(selectedItem.id)`. Autocomplete allows user to select item by mouse click or by pressing `enter` on the keyboard.

If suggested item is:

```
{
  "name": "Apple",
  "id": "1000"
}
```

I expect after selecting it, the ngModel value will be selected item's `id` - `1000`.

- In Chrome it works OK - it sets `$viewValue` and `$modelValue` correctly (`$modelValue=1000`).
- In Firefox it sets model as in Chrome (`$modelValue=1000`), but when I click somewhere else - make blur (then browser probably fires `change` event), model changes and it becomes same as visible input value (`$modelValue='Apple'`).
- In IE 11 it sets model correct only when I select item with mouse click. If I select it by pressing `enter`, the model becomes visible input value (`$modelValue='Apple'`)

Here is plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/o2Jkgprf8EakGqnpu22Y?p=preview

I'd like to reach the same behavior in every browser. How to deal with that problems?

Comment: I think you're far better of using two distinct models, one which holds the resolved async value (probably private), and one which the user uses to type the query (public). As it stands, when one types in a complete bogus name (one which is not in the list of fruits), this will then be the model value. Which probably issn't really helpful when you expect it to be an ID.

Comment: @Yoshi, That what you've mentioned it's only a validation improvement - user will not be able to type something other than id, but It doesn't solve the problem. (Or I don't know how to implement it properly). With your hints it'd be something like that: http://plnkr.co/edit/7nCAEhIXX2wGNR18eRqk. `$modelValue = null` for bogus names, but in firefox parser function is still run again on blur, so I lose my selected value.

Comment: If it's the events alone, you could try using [`ngModelOptions.updateOn`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions).

Comment: @Yoshi, private model was a solution. I only had to add one validation in parser function. I've posted an explained answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I've made it. The solution is based on [Yoshi's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336086/ngmodel-how-to-deal-with-its-different-behavior-in-different-browsers/31474185?noredirect=1#comment50733041_31336086) and it uses local model to keep selected data.

When user selects something, local model is set to selected `Object` and `$viewValue` is set to the text value of selected item. Then parser sets `id` property of local model as `$modelValue`.

```
select: function(event, ui) {
  if(ui.item && ui.item.data){
    model = ui.item.data
    ngModel.$setViewValue(model.name);
    scope.$apply();
  }
}

ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
  if(_.isObject(model) && value!==model.name){
    model = value;
    return model;
  }
  return model.id;
});
```

Parser function do also one important thing. Because it's run when user type something or on the `change` event (that was the problem in firefox!), it checks if the value is same as current local model's text value, and if not it changes local model into this value. It means that if parser function is run by `change` event value would be the same as text value, so `$modelValue` is not changed, but if user type something model is updated to the typed value (it becomes `String`).

Validator function checks if local model is an `Object`. If not it means that field is invalid so by default its `$modelValue` disappears.

Here is the plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/2ZkXFvgLIwDljfJoyeJ1?p=preview

(In formatter function I return that what comes, so `$viewValue` is temporarily an `Object` but then in `$render` method I call `$setViewValue` to set `$viewValue` and `$modelValue` correctly, so it becomes `String`. I heard `$setViewValue` should not be run in `$render` method, but I don't see other way to set correct `$modelValue` when something comes from outside).

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be related to http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8878

As pointed out in the above link, the change event is triggered only in Firefox and not in Chrome. So in your case, $setViewValue is again triggered when clicked outside and the model value is set to "Apple".

There is change callback for autocomplete jquery ui widget. To handle both the case/browsers may be you would have to explicitly set view value again on this call back (and it works).

http://plnkr.co/edit/GFxhzwieBJTSL8zjSPSZ?p=preview

```
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
      elem.on('change', function(){
      // This will not be printed in Chrome and only on firefox
      console.log('change');
    });


    select: function(event, ui) {
      ngModel.$setViewValue(ui.item.data.id);
      scope.$apply();
    },
    // To handle firefox browser were change event is triggered
    // when clicked outside/blur
    change: function(event, ui) {
      ngModel.$setViewValue(ui.item.data.id);
      scope.$apply();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it's not perfect solution, but it may help. Also, it doesn't solve the problem with `enter` key in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I had similiar fights with the `ngModelController` and `$setViewValue`.

Eventually I looked for alternative solutions. 
One approach that I found which worked pretty well was to create a new element as component directive which includes the input tag as a transcluded element.

```
app.directive('fruitAutocomplete', function($http) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: 'ngModel',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelController) {
      var $input = elem.find('input');

      $input.autocomplete({
        ...
      });
    }
  }
})
```

In the HTML:

```
<fruit-autocomplete name="fruit" ng-model="model.fruit">
  <input ng-disabled="inputDisabled" placeholder="input fruit"/>
</fruit-autocomplete>
```

Here is a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bz42zyrRb1VITXqwm4Z4?p=preview)

With this proposed solution you can isolate the `ngModelController` and the jQueryUI modal interplay to its own custom element and it does not interfere with the "normal" `<input>` tag and you are not concerned by the jQueryUI bug.

By using the `<input>` tag as transcluded element you can still benefit from most the Angular input goodies like `ng-disabled`, `placeholder`, etc...

Comment: In this solution, you lose much default functionality. E.g. You cannot set `placeholder`, you either cannot use `ng-change` or `ng-disabled`. It' might be ok when you want to use your directive for really specific cases, but not if you're building reusable directive which will be used in large application ;)

Comment: Challenge accepted!
Please consider my updated answer by using transclusion.